# template class constructor syntax

Tags: c++, templates, computational-geometry

I am working on [Michael Laszlo's book on computational geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132908425) and have become confused with an unsual kind of template class constructors syntax he has used.

**1st code**

```
template<class T> class ListNode :public Node{
public:
    T _val;
    ListNode(T val);
    friend class List<T>;
};

template class<T> ListNode::ListNode(T val)  : // shouldn't this be template <class T> ListNode <T>::ListNode(T val)
   _val(val)
{
}
```

**Question**

Shouldn't the syntax be `ListNode <T>::ListNode(T val)`  instead of `ListNode ::ListNode(T val)` ?

Comment: Does that actually compile? [Mine doesn't.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f29d65bbb14364b8b7227670a30221a8-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f)

Comment: errors that appear .. `ray1.cpp:38:15: error: expected identifier before ‘<’ token
ray1.cpp:38:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
`..

Comment: @chris +1 for using Coliru. :)

Comment: @chris since your error and my error aren't the same, could the error be due to something else? and plus I was wondering that since it is an inherited class,, wouldn't that matter to some extent?

Comment: @nerorevenge You must have mistyped that `template class<T>`.

Comment: That's funny, according to [this](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/compgeom/books.html), that book is the only one in the list that is not recommended.

Comment: @Reubens yep , true, now the errors are pretty much the same

Comment: @nerorevenge, The only difference the base class makes in the definition is a possible `: Node(...), _val(val)`.

Comment: @chris thanks for answer and plus I checked out that website ,weird and I wonder why it isn't recommended

Comment: @nerorevenge, There's all sorts of reasons why a book could be frowned upon, such as bad, or more importantly, wrong, explanations, code that doesn't compile or has logic errors in it that are not discussed immediately after, with a bold notice that they exist, or using techniques that are generally bad. I think the most important thing to most people is that the statements in the book are factual and a good representation of what they're discussing, not something that uses bad practices everywhere, or is plain wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided will not compile. You're absolutely right that it should be `ListNode<T>::ListNode(T val)` (although passing by value is debatable). If you check the book's errata, you might be able to find this in there.